# how to escape quote when updating database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

The code below will give errors everytime it runs, because of the quote within quote `"<span id="1">3</span>`", I cannot change the quote structure, as this was the format that must be saved in the database, can cakephp3 somehow escape the values when saving this to database?

```
$sql='update tags set description ="<span id="1">3</span>"';
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$stmt = $connection->execute($sql);
```

Comment: Why are you not using Tables and Models to handle this?

Comment: it is easier is to use the table, but there are a lot of important data on the table, and I am only in charge of updating some columns, so I just want to make sure that I will not accidentally update other data in other columns, I am new to CakePHP 3, hence, trying to play it safe

Answer (score 0):

seems like below will escape the quote correctly

```
$desc_to_be_save="<span id="1">3</span>"
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$connection->update('tags', ['description' => $desc_to_be_save], ['id' => 3]);
```

Comment: Is there some good reason why you're using the connection directly instead of with tables and entities? Anyway, yes, this should work (apart from your shown initialization of `$desc_to_be_save` being invalid); always best to avoid directly calling `execute` whenever possible, to avoid injection attacks and other such issues.

Comment: it is easier is to use the table, but there are a lot of important data on the table, and I am only in charge of updating some columns, so I just want to make sure that I will not accidentally update other data in other columns, I am new to CakePHP 3, hence, trying to play it safe.

Comment: If you read an entity, update your one column, and write the entity back, no other columns will be affected. I mean, unless there's some kind of trigger and stored procedure in the database itself, but then that's going to happen no matter how you update it.

Comment: I'd argue that using raw `update` and `execute` calls is less safe than using entities and `$table->save`.